# Numa lista de checkbox, saber as que estão checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Na minha aplicação estou a imprimir uma lista de dados vinda base de dados, e em cada item da lista estou a colocar uma checkbox, como mostra a seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora ao clicar em "Iniciar cópia" quero seleccionar os itens da lista que estão seleccionados, e o respectivo `value`.

A imprimir a lista na view estou a fazer:

```
<div style="width: 40%; height: 60%; overflow-y: scroll;">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.estabelecimentos)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" value="@item.IdFilial" name="filialCopia"/>@item.Nome<br />
    }
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="FazerCopiaEstabs()">Iníciar cópia</button>
```

A `ViewBag.estabelecimentos` é a minha lista de dados retornados do controller.

Agora para ir buscar os valores das checkbox selecionadas estou a fazer (javascript):

```
function FazerCopiaEstabs() {
    var fields = $("input[name='filialCopia']").serializeArray();
    $.each(fields, function (index, itemData) {
        alert(itemData.val());
    })
}
```

No código acima só estou a tentar ir buscar o `value` de cada checkbox seleccionada, para depois enviar para o controller e iniciar a cópia de dados. Mas sem sucesso... Não estou a conseguir ir buscar as dropbox seleccionadas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
function FazerCopiaEstabs() {
        $("input:checkbox[name=filialCopia]:checked").each(function () {
            alert(this.value);
        });
    }
```