# Somar checkbox com valores pré definidos. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, funções, input

Estou tentando somar valores da value que foram selecionados via checkbox com JavaScript puro. No que estou errando ?

Segue linha de código que raciocinei ...

**HTML**

```
<h2>Escolha seus destinos:</h2>
        
        <input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="780.00">
        <label for="pais1">Peru</label>

        <input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="960.00">
        <label for="pais2">Chile</label>

        <input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="870.00">
        <label for="pais3">Bolivia</label>

        <input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="910.00">
        <label for="pais4">Uruguai</label>

        <input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="980.00">
        <label for="pais5">Argentina</label>

        <hr>

        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="350.00">
            <label for="voltar">Deseja passagem de volta ao Brasil?</label>
        </div>

        <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>

        <p class="resultado"></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
function calcular () {
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var peru = document.querySelectorAll('input[valeu="780.00"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
})

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var chile = document.querySelectorAll('input[valeu="960.00"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
})

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var bolivia = document.querySelectorAll('input[valeu="870.00"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
})

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var uruguai = document.querySelectorAll('input[valeu="910.00"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
})

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var argentina = document.querySelectorAll('input[valeu="980.00"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
})

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var voltar = document.querySelectorAll('input[valeu="350.00"][type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
})

var passagem = parseInt(peru) + parseInt(chile) + parseInt(bolivia) + parseInt(uruguai) + parseInt(argentina) + parseInt(voltar);

document.querySelector('.resultado'). innerHTML = passagem;
}
```

Comment: A resposta desta questão te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83463/pegar-valores-checkbox-com-javascript?rq=1

Comment: input[valeu="350.00"] é valeu ou value?

Answer (score 1):

O seu código é muito verboso e com alguns problemas (por exemplo, a utilização da função `parseInt` em vez de `parseFloat` sendo esse utilizado para valores com virgula), pode buscar os elementos selecionados e varrer (`for`) *item* a *item* buscando a propriedade `value` e somando em alguma variável, ***exemplo***:

```js
function calcular() {
  document.querySelector('.resultado').innerHTML = '';
  const itens = document
    .querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  let values = 0; 
  if (itens.length > 0) {
    for(let i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
      values = values + (parseFloat(itens[i].value));
    }
   document.querySelector('.resultado').innerHTML = values
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Escolha seus destinos:</h2>

<input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="780.00">
<label for="pais1">Peru</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="960.00">
<label for="pais2">Chile</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="870.00">
<label for="pais3">Bolivia</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="910.00">
<label for="pais4">Uruguai</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="980.00">
<label for="pais5">Argentina</label>

<hr>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="passagem" value="350.00">
  <label for="voltar">Deseja passagem de volta ao Brasil?</label>
</div>

<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>

<p class="resultado"></p>
```

O exemplo e bem simples utilizado um [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) buscando elementos do tipo `checkbox` e que estejam selecionados e na próxima linha somando os valores para saber o valor final daquelas que estão selecionadas.

Comment: o que na minha resposta está errada?